# Are there Objective Advantages of JSLint over JSHint

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

At the moment we are using JSLint and JSHint. I have tremendous respect for Crockford and his way of using Javascript tightly.  We are programming in the flattened style and have a lot of functions. Occasionally cyclical definitions occur.

'use strict' is a priority.  So we cannot use 'sloppy' or 'undef' options.

Does anyone know of **objective** advantages JSLint has over JSHint?

This is not a question about subjective preferences. I am looking for tips like:

e.g.

- `'regexp'` warns about `.` and `^`, whereas, JSHint seems to only warn about `.` (fine most of the time).
- there is no alternative to `'some_option'`

From the number of different options, they seem to be quite similar. However JSLint seems tighter.

Comment: I think people are moving away from JSLint, and JSHint gets all the praise now. Both are good, but JSHint has more options and it handles ES6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know your question was about advantages of JSLint, but off the top of my head there are very few. But here's what I've come up with:

Advantages of JSHint:

- Support for ES6 syntax (keeps up to date with the spec pretty well too)
- Ability to ignore any warning with the `-Wxxx` options
- A much better web interface
- Much better tooling integration (it's available via npm, well maintained Grunt plugins etc)

Advantages of JSLint:

- Code format validation (still available in JSHint with the `white` option but deprecated and could be removed)
- Enforces the use of a single `var` statement per context (still available in JSHint with the `onevar` option but also deprecated, and questionable whether this is an advantage of JSLint or not)

Comment: fwiw enforced use of single var does sound useful - I can't imagine myself ever doing that on purpose. Perhaps because I was a Java program in a former life. Or C programmer. Or C++. Or Scala. etc.

Comment: @djechlin - It's just a style choice (`var a = 1, b = 2;` instead of `var a = 1; var b = 2;`). Basically JSLint provides a few more rules for enforcing a certain coding style than JSHint does.

Comment: oic, I thought you meant `var cat = "/usr/bin/cat"; /* ... */ var cat = Animal.makeCat();`